# how to change font size in TextInput text when more then 6 char entered in react native?

Tags: react-native, font-size, textinput

I want to change the font size of the text that we are entering in `TextInput` only when the `charLength` more than 6.

The actual font size is 80px, when changing it should be 40 or something like less than it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can give conditional style to the `TextInput` component.

**Example**

```
_onChangeText(text) {
  this.setState({ fontSize: text.length > 6 ? 40 : 80 });
}

render() {
  return (
    // Giving an array of objects to style property can help you to define a -- default value
    <TextInput 
      onChangeText={this._onChangeText.bind(this)}
      style={[ {fontSize: 80}, {fontSize: this.state.fontSize} ]}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: it showing null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.fontSize')

Comment: You need to give initial value of state in your constructor method.

Comment: length of the text should be initiated from 0 ?  constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = {
      count: 0,
   }
}                  like this ? @bennygenel

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. Please update your question with a [mcve] of your current code

Comment: In my example I'm not setting `count`. I'm setting `fontSize`

Comment: yeah that okay instead of count fontSize should be there but i confused with that size, what size should be mentioned there? @bennygenel

Comment: It should be your required initial fontSize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155337/discussion-between-vj-ragavan-and-bennygenel).

Comment: Hey, What If am I using ==> value={this.state. name} ? How can I give another state that is fontSize as in your answer ?